# Opencart/Bootstrap sizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, opencart-3

Hello readers and helpers,

To start off my English isn't the best. Also I don't know how to describe this problem. But I will do my best to describe it.

I'm using the Opencart system with the default theme. And editted a few bits here and there. Also I use bootstrap 3 which is included in opencart 3.x.
For this case: I edited the navbar font size. But if you scale it down to mobile the links will not go to the dropdown menu but stack under each other. Screenshot as example:

[image: screenshot]

If you look closely you can see words under the purple bar.

I've had 2 solutions in mind but don't know how to execute them.

1. Scale the font-size down, which I don't like.
2. Make it so that at some point (when the first words go under the navbar) it automatically will change to the mobile dropdown menu.

Greetings,

Jesse

ps: I'm really sorry for the vague question. I'm doing my best on English here.
If you have any questions for me or need anything. Let me know!

Code snippet:

```css
#menu {
  background-color: #49185E;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #49185E, #3f185e);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #49185E #49185E #49185E;
  min-height: 40px;
  height: 70px;
}

#menu .nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 25px 20px 10px 15px;
  min-height: 25px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#menu .nav>li>a:hover,
#menu .nav>li.open>a {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#menu .dropdown-menu {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#menu .dropdown-inner {
  display: table;
}

#menu .dropdown-inner ul {
  display: table-cell;
}

#menu .dropdown-inner a {
  min-width: 160px;
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#menu .dropdown-inner li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu .see-all {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#menu .see-all:hover,
#menu .see-all:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #49185e;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #49185e, #3b154c);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#menu #category {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#menu .btn-navbar {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-stretch: expanded;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 2px 18px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #49185e;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #511a67, #49185e);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #49185e #49185e #441758;
```

```html
<nav id="menu" class="navbar">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">{{ text_category }}</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <form class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
            <?php echo $cart; ?>
          </form>
        </li>
        {% for category in categories %} {% if category.children %}
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.name }}</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-inner"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {% for child in children %}
                <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endfor %}</div>
            <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a>
          </div>

        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endif %} {% endfor %}

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

And Ofcourse the standard Bootstrap CSS which is the standard .navbar.

Comment: THe problem isn't your english, you should include the code so we can help, now we can't do nothing but guess....

Comment: Allright, Ill add the code. But Its just opencart and bootstrap. Nothing more. I think people would know how the code would've looked like.

Comment: Your English is correct, so is your solutions, You can execute them using media queries, also people here aren't psychics, they may know how code works, but not how you want it laid out, better if you'd include the markup here and don't literally copy it given that you're using some framework, it's better if you include a working snippet that represents the issue, i would recommend running your code and copy the markup from the browser Devtool after everything executes, it's only pure html and css

Comment: In the meanwhile I changed the bootstrap 3 to 4. I've fixed it now. Sorry for making a post.... It just toke me wayyyy to long :D

Status: Fixed.